# How do I disable DVD drive auto-probing in SLES 11 SP2?

Tags: suse, sles, yast

I'm preparing a SLES 11 SP2 VM for use in Azure. One of the steps they require is disabling auto-probing for DVD drives. How do I determine if auto-probing is on?

In the SLES documentation (book_sle_deployment.pdf, Ch. 8.1), it says to use YaST to go to Hardware > Hardware Information, but in the VM that I'm using, there is no "Hardware Information."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options, you can either comment out or remove the line from the `/etc/fstab` or you could specify the `noauto` option, leaving the line intact in the `/etc/fstab` file.

#### Example

```
/dev/dvd    /media/dvd    auto        noauto,rw,user,exec    0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/fstab` just make sure the entry for the DVD drive is not mentioned in there. That should take care of it.